# Notepad++ delete lines

Tags: notepad++

I have this XML file and I am using NOTEPAD++ to edit it.
I have some lines that I need to delete. For example, I have lines like this:

```
<tag1>0</tag1>
<tag2>0</tag2>
<tag3>example</tag3>
```

and I used this command:

```
 <[^<>]+>0</[^<>]+>
```

the result would be

```
<tag3>example</tag3>
```

And it works fine. But now I have another problem. There's some lines with value "0" that shouldn't be deleted. Something like this:

```
<tag1>0</tag1>
<tag2>0</tag2>
<tag3>example</tag3>
<tag>
<tag1>example</tag1>
<tag2>0</tag2>
<tag3>example</tag3>
</tag>
```

and the result i need is

```
<tag3>example</tag3>
<tag>
<tag1>example</tag1>
<tag2>0</tag2>
<tag3>example</tag3>
</tag>
```

I need a command/script to use in notepad that deletes "0" but no between

```
<tag>...</tag>
```

Is there any way to do that? It must be simple, but I don't know how.
Can you help me?

Comment: why this: ***<tag2>0</tag2>*** and not ***<tag1>0</tag1>*** ????

Comment: Probably a typo

Comment: it was a mistake. i corrected it

Comment: If your question is about Notepad++, please don't tag it with the name of a different text editor.